# Variable en metodo new ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

necesito pasar la variable 'cuotas' que traigo de la vista al controlador. Tengo el siguiente codigo de controlador:

```
def create

@financiacion = Aspurc::Financiacion.new(:id_persona=>"#{current_user.affiliate.id_persona}",
                                         :monto_financiado=>'2000',
                                         :cuotas=> params[:cuotas], 
                                         :gtoadmin=>'0')    
@financiacion.save
redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

y mi vista donde paso la variable 'cuotas' en un boton,es la siguiente:

```
<td class="pull-right"><%=  button_to 'Seleccionar', financiations_path(:cuotas => plan_cuotas[0]) , data: { confirm: "El plan de cuotas seleccionado es: '#{plan_cuotas[5]}'. Desea confirmar?" } %></td>
```

alguna posible solucion? porque no me esta tomando la variable 'cuotas' en el controlador

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo de la siguiente manera: asigne a una variable el parametro que traigo de la vista y luego lo inserte en el new como se ve aqui debajo:

```
def create
@cuotas = params[:cuotas]
@financiacion = Aspurc::Financiacion.new(:id_persona=>"# 
{current_user.affiliate.id_persona}",
                                     :monto_financiado=>'2000',
                                     :cuotas=> @cuotas, 
                                     :gtoadmin=>'0')    
@financiacion.save
redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```